# Differentiability of an integral of geodesic distance

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Let $(M,g)$ be an $m$-dimensional Riemannian symmetric space and $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ be the geodesic distance function. Fix any $\alpha\in M$ and $v\in T_\alpha M$ with $\|v\|=1$.

Q1: Define
$$
g(t)=\int_M f(t,x)e^{-f(t,x)}dx,
$$
where $f(t,x)=d^2(Exp_\alpha(tv),x).$  Question: Is $g$ second-order differentiable at $t=0$?

Answer: Here $g$ is a constant function so the answer is yes. This was given by Willie Wong.

---

Q2: There was a typo in the above question. To fix it, we define
$$
h(t)=\int_M f(t,x)e^{-f(0,x)}dx,
$$
where $f(t,x)=d^2(Exp_\alpha(tv),x).$ Question: Is $h$ second-order differentiable at $t=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $G:M\to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$ G(p) = \int_M d^2(p,x) \exp( - d^2(p,x)) ~dx $$
your $g(t)$ is $g(t) = G(\exp_\alpha(tv))$.

As $M$ is a symmetric space, given $p,q$ there exists an isometry that maps $p$ to $q$. So we see obviously that $G(p) = G(q)$.

Hence your function $g$ is the constant function.

Hence the answer to your question is "yes, it is twice differentiable at $t = 0$".

---

(If you intended to ask about a general complete Riemannian manifold $M$ instead of a symmetric space, it would require more work and you should ask a new question.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just found my question had a typo. In its current form, the answer is in fact trivial. I will revise my question now. Sorry about the confusion!